# "In other words" vs "In another words"

Tags: sentence-structure

Sometimes I need to repeat myself "in **other** words" or "in **another** words"?

"It's ugly. In **other / another** words I would say it's not nice".

Answer (score 8):

"In other words" is the preferred usage.

At the very least, "another" is singular, and therefore does not match "words", which is plural.